# Java Flight Recorder - Continuous rolling recording

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, jfr, jmc

#### Question

How to get a **rolling** recording into disk, with a **maximum age**?

#### Context

When something goes bad in my server, I want to be able to dump the profiling information of the hours prior and analyse it, to know what went wrong.

1. As I don't know when things will go bad, the JDK should be continuously saving the events to disk.
2. As the server is not rebooted often, to avoid the files growing unbounded, I need to set some sort of cap (either age, or size).

So, in other words, I wanted the JDK to save the recordings continuously to disk, but remove the older files/recordings such that the total amount remains under a certain threshold (age or size).

To that end, these are the options I have for version `Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144`:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-XX:StartFlightRecording
   name=<foo-bar>
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions
   defaultrecording=true   // what does this do even?
   disk=true
   maxage=1h // this is what I thought would solve my problem! 
   repository=<path-to-where-I-want-the-recording>
   maxchunksize=5M
```

I would have thought that setting `maxage=1h` would only keep the last 1 hour of recording on disk. But no! Its been past 1 day, and the files are not being capped.

At the same time the `maxchunksize` appears to work. The various `.jfr` files have approximately 5M. Of which there are many such files, since the the age capped is not being enforced.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why don't you make a cron job that removes old files?

Comment: @Kayaman Suggesting a workaround doesn't help much with resolving the root cause.

Comment: Asking questions that include `// what does this do even?` don't exactly bring out the best of my customer support qualities out.

Comment: @Kayaman cron jobs add complexity to the system. An extra thing to remember, maintain, document, which results in a brittle system. Additionally, this is a simple behaviour which one would think is expected and in fact needed by most users of JFR, so a "native" solution most likely exists.

Comment: 1. That is what I am doing by posting here. 2. No need to be rude. My question is clear, succinct, well curated. Your frustrations are ill-grounded. 3. I have found no documentation on the meaning of `defaultrecording`. Have you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem, I think, is that you are starting two recordings, one with`-XX:StartFlightRecording` and one with `-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true`.

The one with `-XX:StartFlightRecording` is unbounded. I think the following would be appropriate option for Oracle JDK 1.8.0_144 and your use case:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=repository=<path>
-XX:StartFlightRecording=maxage=1h,name=<name>
```

`-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` is needed because JFR is a commercial feature in Oracle JDK 8. From JDK 11, it's no longer needed.

`-XX:+FlightRecorder` is not needed with `-XX:StartFlightRecoding` for JDK 8u40 or later. The JFR buffers are now setup when the first recording is started, not when the JVM starts. If a recording is started with `defaultrecording=true`, `-XX:+FlightRecorder` is still needed.

`-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=defaultrecording=true` does a lot of things, mostly for historical reasons, but only needed when doing in-memory recordings. From JDK 9, the option is never needed and has been removed.

`-XX:FlightRecorderOptions=disk=true,maxage=1h` isn't needed if `-XX:StartFlightRecording` is used, which is the recommended way to start JFR.

Unless you have an issue, I would keep the `maxchunksize` at the default (12 MB). It's the chunk files size JFR has been optimized for and tested against.

Answer (score 3):

I am accepting `Kire Haglin`'s answer.

Adding a bit more value for what worked for me on this JDK:

```
-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures
-XX:StartFlightRecording
  name=<foo-bar>
  maxage=12h
  dumponexit=true
-XX:FlightRecorderOptions
  dumponexitpath=<path-to-file>.jfr
  disk=true
  repository=<some-folder-path>
```

Notice the extra parameters `dumponexit` and `dumponexitpath`, not present on my original question. I ended up also needing those.
After trial and error, it appears `dumponexit` must exist within the `XX:StartFlightRecording` argument, and `dumponexitpath` on the `FlightRecorderOptions` argument. No other arrangement seems to work.

Notice also that removing `-XX:+FlightRecorder` and `defaultrecording=true` (as Kire suggested) *still* worked. That being said, I don't think the presence of `defaultrecording=true` was triggering a double recording.
I am saying this because when issuing command `jcmd <PID> JFR.check <name>` I only got one entry.

Comment: Did you try "jcmd <PID> JFR.check" without the <name>? If you want a fixed file name (not an autogenerated), you should be able to use -XX:StartFlightRecording=filename=dump.jfr,dumponexit=true,maxage=1h and then only have -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=repository=<some-folder-path>. If you want the filename autogenerated, then -XX:StartFlightRecording can't be used and defaultrecording=true path is needed with dumponexitpath. All this mess was fixed in JDK 9.

Comment: That's a good point about the command without the `<name>`. I no longer remember. If I did issue it with the name, maybe I was indeed triggering two recordings after all. Thanks about the other info. What a mess indeed. xD